# How to calculate $p={{{{{{6^6}^6}^6}^6}^6}^6}$ $\mod7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, power-towers

I've tried two approaches:

**Approach 1**

Since $6 \equiv -1 \pmod7$

So, $p=(-1)^t$ and $t$ is even

Therefore, $p=1$.

**Approach 2**

Since $6 \equiv -1 \pmod7$

So, $6^6 \equiv 1 \pmod7$.

Hence, solving towers from top to bottom:

$p \equiv {{{{{6^6}^6}^6}^6}^1} \pmod7$

$p \equiv {{{6^6}^6}^1} \pmod7$

$p \equiv {6^1} \pmod7$

Therefore, $p=6$.

Now, I don't know why both the approaches are giving different answers and which one is right.

Comment: By your second method $2^6 \equiv 2 $ (mod 5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't replace exponents like that. That is, $6^8\not\equiv 6^1$ mod $7$. You can pretty easily check that $6^8\equiv 1$.

As you say, $6\equiv -1$, so $-1$ to an even power will give you $1$ mod $7$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $6^8 \equiv 1 ~\mod 7$?

Comment: Right, thanks. $ $

Comment: I've not replaced $6^8$ by $6$ anywhere but instead replaced $6^6$ by 1

Comment: That was an example

Comment: I've not considered equality anywhere. only congruence

Comment: I'm not sure how to type a "not equivalent" sign but you could have figured that out form context.

Comment: @ankit you say that, but you considered it as equality only in your approach

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I've consistently used congruence with mod in every step not equality

Comment: $b^{a+7} \not \equiv b^a \mod 7$.  It just isn't.  Congruencies do not distribute over exponents.  They just don't.

Comment: You've used congruence where they are *not* allowed.  If $a \equiv b \mod p $ does **NOT** mean $c^a \equiv c^b \mod p $.

Comment: In fact, for 7 we have $a^{b+6k} \equiv a^b \mod 7$.  That $6$ is NOT a typo.

Comment: So $6^{6^{...}}\equiv 6^0 \equiv 1 tmod 7$.

Answer (score 3):

Approach $1$ is correct.

We do not have $$a^b \equiv a^{(b \mod p)} \mod p$$ in general

Answer (score 1):

Third approach.  $7$ is prime.  $gcd (6,7)=1$ so by Fermats Little theorem  $6^6\equiv 1 \mod 7$.

So $6^{6*k}\equiv 1 \mod 7$  (notice congruence of exponents are **NOT** preserved modulo 7-- but they are preserved modulo 6.)

So as ${{{6^6}^6}^6} $ is a multiple of $6$ we have ${{{{6^6}^6}^6} ^6}\equiv 1 \mod 7$

Answer (score 0):

Question: $p={{{{{{6^6}^6}^6}^6}^6}^6}$ $\mod7$?

- a) Let $Q = {{{{6^6}^6}^6}^6}$ so that $p = 6^{6^Q}$
- b) Note that $6\equiv -1 \pmod 7$

Thus

- $\qquad \displaystyle p=6^{6^Q} = 6^{2^Q \cdot 3^Q} \equiv \left((-1)^{2^Q}\right)^{3^Q} \equiv 1^{3^Q} \equiv 1 \pmod 7$